# Evaluating variables stored inside an array variable and re-sorting that array according to the evaluated values?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

So I have a MySQL database table that stores order ID and prices. The price can either be dynamic or static.

So for example:

Order ID | Price

1|205.99

2|215.95

3|217.88

4|$marketrate

5|$marketrate*1.02

6|212.99

On my php page I have

```
include "prices.php";
$sql="Select `Order ID`, `Price` from `table` ORDERBY `price`";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

        echo "<tr ".$tr_class.">\n";
        foreach ($row as $field=>$value) {


            eval('$value = ' . $value . ';');
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>\n";

        }
        echo "</tr>\n";



    }
```

So you see I use eval() to evaluate the price variable and display it and prices.php defines all the prices like $marketrate and whatnot.

My question is, how can I orderby the evaluated prices? When I use orderby in my mysql statement, it sorts the array based on static numbers and then the variable names $marketrate, which obviously is wrong because $marketrate is not a number. I need it to sort the array according to what the evaluated value of $marketrate is.

**Is it possible to somehow evaluate all the variables in the $result array, and then re-sort the array using a PHP sorting function?**

edit: tried to put eval('$result['Price'] = ' . $result['Price'] . ';'); in there but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Loop throurgh your MySQL results first, put the products in an array, sort the array and then loop through the array to output your HTML table

```
$priceValues = array(); // create an empty array to hold your prices
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    foreach ($row as $field=>$value) {

        eval( '$priceValues[] = ' . $value . ';' ); // append the new value to the array
    }
}

sort( $priceValues ); // sort values from lowest to highest

// Then output the HTMl table
echo "<tr ".$tr_class.">\n";

foreach ($priceValues as $price) {
    echo "<td>" . $price . "</td>\n";
}

echo "</tr>\n";
```

However resorting to `eval` is usually a bad sign and in your case there is no need to do it. You should really **change your table structure** and include a column for the marketrate multiplier. That way you could `select` the product (marketrate * multiplier) directly and sort by product.

Comment: Yeah but then the prices will not correlate to the order ID. I need them to stay correlated.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the mysql results as a clean array with full data in rows, and then use an [`usort()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). It would look like follows, but I've not tested it:

```
include "prices.php";
$sql="Select `Order ID`, `Price` from `table` ORDERBY `price`";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    
    foreach ($row as $field => $value) {
    
        eval('$value = ' . $value . ';');
        $row[$field] = $value; // replace row value
        
    }
    $data[] = $row; // append row to our array
}

// sorting function
usort($data, "order_by_price");

// usort callback
function order_by_price($a, $b) {
    $aprice = intval($a['price']);
    $bprice = intval($b['price']);

    if ($aprice == $bprice)
        return 0;
        
    return ($aprice < $bprice) ? -1 : 1;    
}

// now you have a sorted array
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr ".$tr_class.">\n";
    foreach ($row as $field => $value)
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer as it doesn't address the actual questioned asked, but have you considered having the database do the evaluation and then the sort?

```
SELECT
    OrderId,
    CASE
      -- handle market rate (could be handled below) e.g. OrderId 4 above
      WHEN Price = '$marketrate' THEN market.rate
      -- handle $marketrate*number
      WHEN LEFT(Price,LENGTH('$marketrate*')) = '$marketrate*' 
        THEN RIGHT(price,LENGTH(Price)-LENGTH('$marketrate*')) * market.rate  
      -- handle static prices
      ELSE Price 
    END as Price  
  FROM 
    rates, 
    -- replace this with the table that has the rate if its in the database; 
    --   just make sure it only return one row or add a join condition
    -- if not in a table (you use a web service call etc) you could use a parameter,
    --   remove this line, and replace market.rate above
    (SELECT 202 as rate) market
  ORDER BY
    Price
```

You might want to replace some of the LENGTH surrounding static strings, but I was trying to avoid using "magical numbers" and keep it as clear as possible.

## Edit:

I tried quickly adding comments to explain how this works, but as I've received feedback of not understanding, I thought I'd expand a bit.

### Case Statement Explanation

Basically the CASE statement takes whatever is in the price field and tries to convert it to a numeric price (you can of think of the WHEN as an IF).

```
WHEN Price = '$marketrate' THEN market.rate
```

says if the price is listed as market rate (e.g. OrderId 4) then just return the marketrate.

```
WHEN LEFT(Price,LENGTH('$marketrate')) = '$marketrate'
```

says if the price starts with market rate $marketrate

```
THEN RIGHT(price,LENGTH(Price)-LENGTH('$marketrate*')) * market.rate
```

then take everything to the right of $marketrate* and multiple it by the market rate.

Let's look at this using the example of Order Id 5 above: $marketrate*1.02
This works by taking the length of price (16) and subtracting the length of $marketrate* (12) to get 4.  It then takes the right four characters (1.02) and multiplies it by the market rate

```
ELSE Price
```

Finally, it assumes if the string isn't $marketrate and doesn't start with $marketrate, that it will be a number representing a static price.  This could be a bad assumption (e.g. $marketrate+1.02), but with the provided data it works and this was meant primarily as a suggestion and not a canned solution

### Test Database Configuration

I created a table called rates and populated it with data:

```
select OrderId,Price from rates;

+---------+------------------+
| OrderId | Price            |
+---------+------------------+
|       1 | 205.99           |
|       2 | 215.95           |
|       3 | 217.88           |
|       4 | $marketrate      |
|       5 | $marketrate*1.02 |
|       6 | 212.99           |
+---------+------------------+
```

### Add The Rate

In order to use the case statement, the query needs to know the current market rate.  Since I was lazy and split the cases of $marketrate and $marketrate*x, I need the rate twice.  Rather then hardcoding it twice, I'm joining an ad hoc table with one column and one row containing my fake current rate.

```
SELECT OrderId, Price, market.rate  FROM rates, (SELECT 202 as rate) market ORDER BY Price;
+---------+------------------+------+
| OrderId | Price            | rate |
+---------+------------------+------+
|       4 | $marketrate      |  202 |
|       5 | $marketrate*1.02 |  202 |
|       1 | 205.99           |  202 |
|       6 | 212.99           |  202 |
|       2 | 215.95           |  202 |
|       3 | 217.88           |  202 |
+---------+------------------+------+
```

### CASE Statement Example

If you append the case statement to the select clause of the above query then you get:

```
SELECT
    OrderId,
    Price,
    market.rate,
    CASE
      -- handle when its just the market rate
      WHEN Price = '$marketrate' THEN market.rate

      -- handle cases of $marketrate*number
      WHEN LEFT(Price,LENGTH('$marketrate')) = '$marketrate'
         THEN RIGHT(price,LENGTH(Price)-LENGTH('$marketrate')-1) * market.rate  

      -- handle static prices
      ELSE Price 
    END as Price2  
  FROM
    rates,
    (SELECT 202 as rate) market;

+---------+------------------+------+--------+
| OrderId | Price            | rate | Price2 |
+---------+------------------+------+--------+
|       1 | 205.99           |  202 | 205.99 |
|       2 | 215.95           |  202 | 215.95 |
|       3 | 217.88           |  202 | 217.88 |
|       4 | $marketrate      |  202 | 202    |
|       5 | $marketrate*1.02 |  202 | 206.04 |
|       6 | 212.99           |  202 | 212.99 |
+---------+------------------+------+--------+
```

### Add Sorting

Finally, the point of all of this was to obtain the data in a sorted fashion, so sort it by appending ORDER BY Price2

```
SELECT
    OrderId,
    Price,
    market.rate,
    CASE
      -- handle when its just the market rate
      WHEN Price = '$marketrate' THEN market.rate

      -- handle cases of $marketrate*number
      WHEN LEFT(Price,LENGTH('$marketrate')) = '$marketrate'
         THEN RIGHT(price,LENGTH(Price)-LENGTH('$marketrate')-1) * market.rate  

      -- handle static prices
      ELSE Price 
    END as Price2  
  FROM
    rates,
    (SELECT 202 as rate) market
  ORDER BY
    Price2;

+---------+------------------+------+--------+
| OrderId | Price            | rate | Price2 |
+---------+------------------+------+--------+
|       4 | $marketrate      |  202 | 202    |
|       1 | 205.99           |  202 | 205.99 |
|       5 | $marketrate*1.02 |  202 | 206.04 |
|       6 | 212.99           |  202 | 212.99 |
|       2 | 215.95           |  202 | 215.95 |
|       3 | 217.88           |  202 | 217.88 |
+---------+------------------+------+--------+
```

To try to make it easier to read I cheated in my Order by; MySql will let you reference a calculated column (e.g. Price2) in the Order By, but not every RDBMS will.

If the above SQL doesn't work, then copy the CASE statement into the ORDER BY (e.g.)

```
SELECT
    OrderId,
    Price,
    market.rate,
    CASE
      -- handle when its just the market rate
      WHEN Price = '$marketrate' THEN market.rate

      -- handle cases of $marketrate*number
      WHEN LEFT(Price,LENGTH('$marketrate')) = '$marketrate'
         THEN RIGHT(price,LENGTH(Price)-LENGTH('$marketrate')-1) * market.rate  

      -- handle static prices
      ELSE Price 
    END as Price2  
  FROM
    rates,
    (SELECT 202 as rate) market
  ORDER BY
    CASE
      -- handle when its just the market rate
      WHEN Price = '$marketrate' THEN market.rate

      -- handle cases of $marketrate*number (e.g. OrderId 5 above)
      WHEN LEFT(Price,LENGTH('$marketrate')) = '$marketrate'
         THEN RIGHT(price,LENGTH(Price)-LENGTH('$marketrate')-LENGTH('*')) * market.rate  

      -- handle static prices (e.g. OrderId 1, 2, 3, 6)
      ELSE Price 
    END
```

Comment: I also would add that if this were a site I was creating and I controlled the database, I would put the static price in one table and the ones based on a factor of the market rate in a different one.

If some one wanted market rate, then you could use the factor of market rate table with a value of 1.